# php Codeigniter not calling function of class

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project, I am using codeigniter version 2.1.3 and php version 5.5.30 
When I call any function it didn't process it and show nothing in result.

Only constructor of class is called and other functions didn't

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public $em;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Front_main');
        $this->load->model('Front_expertweb');
        log_message('debug', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
                 $a=12;
                 $b=12;
                echo $a+$b;
    }
   public function index_()
   {
       $data=array();
       header("Location:/co/home");
   }
}
```

when I call index_ or other member functions it shows blank page but the constructor result shows.

What is problem in it and how it will solve?

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: i am calling them through url e.g localhost/main/index_
or any other function that i called it shows 24 in result ... constructor result not process or show content of this called function

Answer (score 0):

Re write your index function as below

```
public function index()
   {
       $data=array();
       $this->load->view("co/home");
   }
```

Make Sure that you load URL helper.

Comment: actually its showing only constructor content and not calling other functions when we call them

Comment: did you remove your `index.php` in config file. have properly configured your `.htaccess`

Comment: yeah everything is configured ... its not working still... i am using hooks in it it is showing the result of hook function but not call function

Answer (score 0):

Under `__construct()` why you wrote this? I think you should remove this line.

```
echo $a+$b;
```

Also as far as I see you're not passing anything to the view, so you don't need `$data=array()` line. Delete it.

Try this and make sure that you have this file: /views/co/home.php:

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('co/home');
}
```

You have to write file location, not URL. Probably you're writing URL.